# LinqtoSQL filter and order by syntax

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

My Techie Bretheren (and Sisteren, of course!),

I have a LinqToSql data model that has the following entities:
[data model http://danimal.acsysinteractive.com/images/advisor.jpg](http://danimal.acsysinteractive.com/images/advisor.jpg)

I need to retrieve all advisors for a specific office, ordered by their sequence within the office. I've got the first part working with a join:

```
public static List<Advisor>GetOfficeEmployees(int OfficeID)
{
    List<Advisor> lstAdvisors = null;
    using (AdvisorDataModelDataContext _context = new AdvisorDataModelDataContext())
    {
        var advisors = from adv in _context.Advisors
                       join advisoroffice in _context.OfficeAdvisors
                           on adv.AdvisorId equals advisoroffice.AdvisorId
                       where advisoroffice.OfficeId == OfficeID
                       select adv;

        lstAdvisors = advisors.ToList();

    }
    return lstAdvisors;
}
```

However, I can't seem to wrap my weary brain around the order by clause. Can anyone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from adv in _context.Advisors
where adv.OfficeAdvisor.Any(off => off.OfficeId == officeID)
order adv by adv.OfficeAdvisor.First(off => off.OfficeId = officeID).Sequence
select adv;
```

Comment: This seems like a strange way to do joins with those Any() and First() calls. Even if it works correctly, it is probably creating unnecesary sub-queries in the SQL translation. Why not use a "join" clause, or two "from" clauses with a "where" clause tying them together?

Comment: OO brain wants to work with the Advisor object and its properties.  Data brain wants to join it all together and sort out the type at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Advisor>GetOfficeEmployees(int OfficeID)
{
    List<Advisor> lstAdvisors = null;
    using (AdvisorDataModelDataContext _context = new AdvisorDataModelDataContext())
    {
        var advisors = from adv in _context.Advisors
                       join advisoroffice in _context.OfficeAdvisors
                           on adv.AdvisorId equals advisoroffice.AdvisorId
                       where advisoroffice.OfficeId == OfficeID
                       group adv by adv.OfficeId into g
                       order by g.Sequence
                       select g;

        lstAdvisors = advisors.ToList();

    }
    return lstAdvisors;
}
```

---

**Note:** I am not able to currently test this on Visual Studio but should work.

Comment: There is no need to group the results. In fact, the result of this LINQ query will be an IEnumerable<IGrouping<TSequence, Advisor>>, so this will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an order by clause like this:

```
var advisors = from adv in _context.Advisors
                  join advisoroffice in _context.OfficeAdvisors
               on adv.AdvisorId equals advisoroffice.AdvisorId
               where advisoroffice.OfficeId == OfficeID
               orderby advisoroffice.Sequence //  < -----
               select adv;
```